# Cambiar el tipo de datos de los operadores aritméticos dentro de una lista, Python

Tags: python

Se me da un archivo con varios numeros y signos aritmeticos, pero como saben pasa que cuando se lee un archivo se leen todos los elementos como str, y quiero cambiar los signos aritmeticos de str a signos funcionales, para realizar operaciones con ellos, este es mi código:

```
txt_file = open("Challenge21.txt", "r+", encoding="utf-8")
    
numbers = []
operators = []
total_list = []

for line in txt_file.readlines():
    total_list.extend(line.strip())

for i in range(len(total_list)):
    if total_list[i] not in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
        total_list[i] = int(total_list[i])

print(total_list)
```

Esta es la salida cuando no trato de convertir los signos:

```
[5, '+', 2, '-', 1, '*', 8, '-', 1, 5, '+', 4, '/', 2]
```

Cuando trato de convertirlos con eval(), pasa esto:

```
txt_file = open("Challenge21.txt", "r+", encoding="utf-8")
    
numbers = []
operators = []
total_list = []

for line in txt_file.readlines():
    total_list.extend(line.strip())

for i in range(len(total_list)):
    if total_list[i] not in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
        total_list[i] = int(total_list[i])

    if total_list[i] in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
        total_list[i] = eval(total_list[i])


print(total_list)
```

Y este es el error que me tira:

```
Exception has occurred: SyntaxError
invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
  File "C:\XXXX\xxxx\XXXXX\XXXXX\X\X", line 504, in <module>
    total_list[i] = eval(total_list[i])
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Que puedo hacer?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola xx, bienvenido, esto es SOes, el idioma soportado es el español, te sugiero que traduzcas tu pregunta o la traslades a SO, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Gracias, me había confundido de SO, disculpa...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según entiendo, el problema está en lo que envías a **eval**, que es básicamente un array de letras, cuando deberías enviarle una cadena tipo: **"5+1-4*5/2"** (con o sin espacios).
Hice una pequeña implementación...

Partiendo de la premisa de que tienes algo como:

```
total_list = [
    [ 5, '+', 2, '-', 1, '*', 8, '-', 15, '+', 4, '/', 2 ],
    [ 4, '+', 1, '-', 5, '*', 9, '-', 5, '+',3 , '/', 7 ]
]
```

Creamos la función que va a ejecutar el cálculo.

```
def calcular( numbers, operators ):   
       # hay más números que operadores, por lo que usamos como condición, 
       # la longitud de "operators"
       # usamos la variable "num" para ir guardando los parciales
    num = numbers[0]        
    for i in range( len( operators )):

           # le pasamos a "eval" el número almacenado, el operador y el siguiente número
        num = eval ( f"{num} {operators[ i ]} {numbers[ i + 1 ]}"  )
       # print(num)

numbers = []
operators = []

   #recorremos el array de datos y guardamos los operadores y números en listas
for i in range( len( total_list )):
    for k in range( len( total_list[ i ] )):
        if total_list[ i ][ k ] not in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
            numbers.append( total_list[ i ][ k ] )
        else:
            operators.append( total_list[ i ][ k ] )

       # terminada la carga, llamamos a la función **calcular**.
    calcular( numbers, operators )
```

Si necesitas guardar en la lista original los resultados, haces que **calcular** devuelva el valor conseguido y se lo asignas.